# C# Threads - Interruption

Tags: c#, multithreading

Normally will we interrupt a thread which is in "WaitSleepJoin" state or "Running" state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you don't interrupt a thread at all... but if you try to, it won't actually be interrupted until it next blocks. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx):

> If this thread is not currently
>   blocked in a wait, sleep, or join
>   state, it will be interrupted when it
>   next begins to block.
>
> ThreadInterruptedException is thrown
>   in the interrupted thread, but not
>   until the thread blocks. If the thread
>   never blocks, the exception is never
>   thrown, and thus the thread might
>   complete without ever being
>   interrupted.

Comment: Jon please give some example with comment.

Comment: An example of what? I can't remember the last time I wanted to interrupt a thread, and it would be pointless without context to be honest. The call itself is simple enough...