# interrupting thread in C#

Tags: c#, thread-sleep

Is there a way to interrupt the system.thread.sleep method that the backgroundWorker is running in this program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace BackGroundWorkerCancel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //This simulates a synchronous download


           Thread.Sleep(2000);
           MessageBox.Show("Thread.Sleep done");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Cancel backgroundWorker1 before thread.sleep method completes



        }


    }
}
```

Comment: There is [Thread.Interrupt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt(v=vs.110).aspx), but it's generally not the "correct" way to handle such a task (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809022/c-sharp-threads-interruption) for what this "interrupt" actually means). The BackgroundWorker itself has a Cancel mechanism (see [AsyncCancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx)), which is likely more appropriate here when employed correctly - eg. sleep a bit, check the flag, sleep a bit.

Comment: You should take a look at the [System.Threading.Tasks.Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That linked question will not *quite* apply to your case, but the gist of it is that you cannot interrupt a sleeping `BackgroundWorker` thread. The method that performs the work has to cooperate by periodically checking the "cancellation pending" flag. See linked question for an example.

Comment: @stakx I don't believe it is a duplicate of *that* question. This question clearly has a `Sleep(some delay)` and *no* loop. Being a BackgroundWorker is secondary in context. The `Sleep` *can* be interrupted (even if the approach is ill-advised to begin with) which will in turn terminate the shown BackgroundWorker as control reaches the end of the method.

Comment: @user2864740: In that case, feel free to write an answer about it; or suggest another question of which this is a duplicate. The code suggests that the question actually *is* about interrupting a `BackgroundWorker` in specific (see comment in 2nd event handler). Concerning the `Thread.Sleep`, see my comment above.

Comment: You're right that a sleeping thread *can* be interrupted, *but* that requires you to first have a reference to it; which again requires its cooperation. (You'd have to catch the value of `Thread.CurrentThread` inside the `…_DoWork` handler method, before the sleep commences, then expose that thread reference e.g. via a field. *Then* the thread could be interrupted from the "outside". But: you could just as well do shorter sleeps, and check the "cancellaton pending" flag in-between, which would be more in line with how `BackgroundWorker` is supposed to work. Thus see the linked-to question.